# How to loop through MultiSelectList posted values and insert each into a new database row in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've visited every search result I could find but I'm stuck.

I'm working on a "dvd store" website using ASP.Net MVC 5, and I'm having some difficulty with inserting MultiSelectList values into the database. The database structure has a many-to-many table which stores the movie Id, genre Id, and a primary key. There's also a movie table with fields like movie title, cost, image path, director, rating, etc.

My insert logic works for putting data into the movies table, but I have a multiselectlist in my Create view which is populated from a list of movie genres in the database. When I select one list item, the ID inserts into the moviegenre table just fine. When I select more than one, only one ID is inserted. I'd like to insert a new row for each selection, with the movie ID and the genre ID (i.e. if 3 genres are selected, create 3 new rows with the same movie id but different genre id's for each row).

How can I iterate through the posted MultiSelectList data and insert a new row for each value?

This is the code in my View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(r => r.CMovie.GenreId, new MultiSelectList(Model.CGenreList, "Id", "Description"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MovieGenresDirectorsRatings mgdr) // The ViewModel
    {
        try
        {
            mgdr.CMovie.Insert();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            return View(mgdr);
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class MovieGenresDirectorsRatings
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GenreId { get; set; }
    public CGenreList CGenreList { get; set; }
    public CDirectorList CDirectorList{ get; set; }
    public CFormatList CFormatList { get; set; }
    public CRatingList CRatingList { get; set; }
    public CGenre CGenre { get; set; }
    public CMovie CMovie { get; set; }        
}
```

And my Insert logic in the Model:

```
public void Insert()
    {
        using (myEntities dc = new myEntities())
        {
            try
            {        
                tblMovie movie = new tblMovie();

                // Add movie to tblMovie
                movie.Id = 1;
                if (dc.tblMovies.Any()) 
                    movie.Id = dc.tblMovies.Max(p => p.Id) + 1;

                this.Id = movie.Id;
                movie.Title = this.Title;
                movie.Description = this.Description;
                movie.ImagePath = this.ImagePath;
                movie.Cost = this.Cost;
                movie.RatingId = this.RatingId;
                movie.FormatId = this.FormatId;
                movie.DirectorId = this.DirectorId;

                try
                {
                    tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre();
                    genre.Id = 1;
                    if (dc.tblMovieGenres.Any())
                        genre.Id = dc.tblMovieGenres.Max(p => p.Id) + 1; 

                    // THIS IS THE PART that I'm struggling with. 
                    // I think the data is there, I'm just not sure how to access it
                    foreach (var GenreId in GenreId) // This line is probably wrong, but I'm not sure how to access the data
                    {
                        genre.GenreId = this.GenreId.FirstOrDefault();
                        genre.MovieId = movie.Id;
                        dc.tblMovieGenres.Add(genre);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                dc.tblMovies.Add(movie);

                // Commit changes
                dc.SaveChanges();

                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried foreach loops and for loops and I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit #1:** After making a few changes, here is my (current and non-working) complete Insert logic in the CMovie class. When I only choose one "genre" from the MultiSelectList, it works fine and inserts into both tables properly. However, when I select two or more "genres" from the MultiSelectList, I get a "Value cannot be null, parameter name: items" error.

```
public void Insert()
{
    using (dbEntities2 oDc = new dbEntities2())
    {
        try
        {        
            tblMovie movie = new tblMovie();
            // Add movie to tblMovie
            movie.Id = 1;
            if (oDc.tblMovies.Any()) // If table is not empty
                movie.Id = oDc.tblMovies.Max(p => p.Id) + 1;
                this.Id = movie.Id;
                movie.Title = this.Title;
                movie.Description = this.Description;
                movie.ImagePath = this.ImagePath;
                movie.Cost = this.Cost;
                movie.RatingId = this.RatingId;
                movie.FormatId = this.FormatId;
                movie.DirectorId = this.DirectorId;

                try
                {
                    foreach (var GenreId in GenreIds)
                    {
                        tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre();
                        genre.Id = 1;
                        if (oDc.tblMovieGenres.Any())
                        {
                            genre.Id = oDc.tblMovieGenres.Max(p => p.Id) + 1; // genre.Id is set to the highest id in the table, +1
                        }
                        genre.Id = this.Id;
                        genre.GenreId = GenreId;
                        genre.MovieId = movie.Id;
                        oDc.tblMovieGenres.Add(genre);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                oDc.tblMovies.Add(movie);

                // Commit changes
                oDc.SaveChanges();

                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

---

**Edit 2:** I've found a solution to the problem. Hopefully this helps someone else having the same issue. I changed the create to use a dropdownlist instead of a multiselectlist, and modified the edit method to allow for updating of multiple genres.

Inside the `CMovie` Model, I created two new methods, `AddGenre` and `DeleteGenre`. In the controller, I added four new `IEnumerable<int>` variables: oldGenreIds, newGenreIds, adds, and deletes.

I then made a list from the `IEnumerable` deletes and adds:

```
IEnumerable<int> deletes = oldGenreIds.Except(newGenreIds);
IEnumerable<int> adds = newGenreIds.Except(oldGenreIds);

deletes.ToList().Foreach(a => mgdr.CMovie.DeleteGenre(id, a));
adds.ToList().Foreach(a => mgdr.CMovie.AddGenre(id, a));
```

The update method is then called, which sets the changed values (including the movie title, description, image path, etc):

```
mgdr.CMovie.Update();
```

By moving the ForEach logic into the controller, I was able to call the `AddGenre` method several times - which I wasn't able to do when calling it directly inside the `Insert` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post method should accept array rather than single object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MovieGenresDirectorsRatings[] mgdr) // The ViewModel
{
    foreach(var genr in mgdr){
          try
          {
              genr.CMovie.Insert(); //inserting each object received from view. 
              return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              throw ex;
              return View(mgdr);
          }
    }
}
```

The idea is receive all objects from view. Even if your view is posting all the items from multiselect list, you need array like structure in your controller to get data from view. Once you have that data in controller, you loop through all of them inserting one by one.

Comment: This is not correct because the OP is already getting IEnumerable<int> GenreId. See my answer please.

Comment: When I change the object to an array, I get an error that MovieGenresDirectorsRatings does not contain a definition for CMovie (`genr.CMovie.Insert()` )

Comment: Your answer was selected because it was the most helpful in assisting me to solve my problem. I ended up finding an alternative solution (see Edit #2) but you were very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem (an overlook actually):

```
 tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre();
 // code...
 foreach (var GenreId in GenreId)
 {
     genre.GenreId = this.GenreId.FirstOrDefault();
     // code
     dc.tblMovieGenres.Add(genre);
 }
```

So see in the above code you create one `tblMovieGenre` and then in your loop you keep adding the same instance of `tblMovieGenres` over and over again. So essentially you add a single `tblMovieGenres` with values from the last iteration in your loop.

**Fix**

To fix the issue move the instantiation inside the loop:

```
 foreach (var GenreId in GenreId)
 {
     tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre();
     // code...
     dc.tblMovieGenres.Add(genre);
  }
```

**Other Suggestions**

**1**

Hungarian notation is not encouraged in .NET so prefixing your database tables with `tbl` is not only a notation problem but makes your code harder to read, especially when you use an ORM. Therefore, if you remove the `tbl` from table names, your code will be:

`MovieGenere` instead of `tblMovieGenre`.

**2**

Also, if I look at one line of code and I can figure out the type of the object, I always use `var` instead. Like this:

```
tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre();
var genre = new tblMovieGenre();
```

That is a personal preference (less typing).

But if I cannot figure the type from reading the single line, then I do not use `var`:

```
tblMovieGenre genre = GetMovie();
```

**3**

If you make your table primary key columns `identity` columns starting at 1, then you will not need such code:

```
movie.Id = 1;
if (dc.tblMovies.Any()) 
    movie.Id = dc.tblMovies.Max(p => p.Id) + 1;
```

Whenever you create a new object in code, it will have an ID of 0 and when you add it to the db, EF will treat it like a new record and generate a new identity for it. This takes the responsibility of managing IDs away from you, which means less coding.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for taking the time to reply. I forgot to mention that this is for a school project, and Hungarian notation is what my instructor recommends, as well as how the objects are instantiated ( `tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre()` ), so it's the only way I've been taught. 

When I instantiate the tblMovieGenre inside the foreach loop, it still works when inserting one, but it throws a "value cannot be null, paramater name: items" exception when I select more than one genre from the multiselectlist. Your solution makes sense, I just need to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: I've also tried this for loop:

`for (var i = 0; i<GenreId.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            tblMovieGenre genre = new tblMovieGenre();
                            genre.Id = 1;
                            if (dc.tblMovieGenres.Any())
                            {
                            // CODE
`

but the foreach loop doesn't work either.

Comment: @mark Please post the code for `CGenre` class so I can see why that error is being thrown.

Comment: The CGenre class is for inserting genres with an Id and a Description (genre name) into the tblGenre table (which populates the selectlist on the view). I feel like I could fix this easily by adding a CMovieGenre class with separate insert logic for that table, but the instructor specifically told us not to do create that class. If you still want to see the CGenre class I'll post the code, but it's completely unrelated to inserting into the movieGenre table.

Comment: Sorry I meant `tblMovieGenre`.

Comment: I'm not sure which code you want to see, there is no tblMovieGenre class.

Comment: @Mark for sure the class is there. Put the cursor over `tblMovieGenre` and then press `F12` and that should show you the class. I need to figure out why it is giving you this error: `value cannot be null, paramater name: items` so I need to know what `items` is. Without the code, I cannot tell.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks for clarifying. 

tblMovieGenre is a public partial class with 3 variables: 
`public int ID { get;set; } 
 public int MovieId {get;set;} public int GenreId {get;set;}`